# Changing part of active URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension

I am a absolute beginner.

I am currently trying to create a chrome plugin that will change part of the URL and then load the new URL in the same tab.

I think I have the most part of the plugin figured out, but I am stuck on the JS that is supposed to this.

So far I have the following (language.js);

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() { // on page load
  let url = new URL(window.location.href);

  const NOButton = document.getElementById('NObutton');
  const replace = () => { // the actual replace function you missed
    console.log(NOButton.textContent, url.pathname)
    const isEnglish = url.pathname.indexOf('en-US') != -1; // what is in the pathname
    const from = isEnglish ? 'en-US' : 'nb-NO'; // one or the other
    const to = isEnglish ? 'nb-NO' : 'en-US'; // one or the other
    url.pathname = url.pathname.replace(from, to)
    NOButton.textContent = isEnglish ? "Norsk" : "English"
    window.history.pushState('', '', url); // uncomment this after testing
  };

  NOButton.addEventListener('click', replace); // add the replace function to the button
  replace(); // initialise the button state
});
```

I have two buttons that will do the essentially the same, only difference is the part of the URL they will change.

-The current script does not work and I can't figure out what I'm mising, what do I need to change to make this work?
-How do I add the second button to this script?
-Or do I need one script for each button?

I expect I need more lines in the JS to make it do what I want it to, but so far I have been unable to find out what.

Let me know if you need more information from me.

**Updates**

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="NObutton">Change</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json (background.js is empty)

```html
{
  "name": "KS En2No Plugin",
  "description": "Place text here",
  "version": "1.0",
  "author": "Place text here",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },

  "permissions": ["storage" , "nativeMessaging" , "notifications" , "tabs"],

  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are missing quotes: `url.replace('/kundesenter/en-US', '/kundesenter/nb-NO')`
- I would use `let url = window.location.href` and possibly `new URL(window.location.href)` and change pathname
- and this belongs in the replace function:
  `window.history.pushState('', '', url.replace('/kundesenter/en-US', '/kundesenter/nb-NO'));`
  but you did not show us that function

Here is ONE button that will toggle the language

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() { // on page load
  // let url = new URL(window.location.href);
  let url = new URL("https://yoursite.no/kundesenter/en-US/page.html"); // remove this and uncomment the line above (remove the //)

  const NOButton = document.getElementById('NObutton');
  const replace = () => { // the actual replace function you missed
    console.log(NOButton.textContent, url.pathname)
    const isEnglish = url.pathname.indexOf('en-US') != -1; // what is in the pathname
    const from = isEnglish ? 'en-US' : 'nb-NO'; // one or the other
    const to = isEnglish ? 'nb-NO' : 'en-US'; // one or the other
    url.pathname = url.pathname.replace(from, to)
    NOButton.textContent = isEnglish ? "Norsk" : "English"
    // window.history.pushState('', '', url); // uncomment this after testing
  };

  NOButton.addEventListener('click', replace); // add the replace function to the button
  replace(); // initialise the button state
});
```

```html
<button id="NObutton">English</button>
```

Your version for your site

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() { // on page load
  let url = new URL(window.location.href);

  const NOButton = document.getElementById('NObutton');
  const replace = () => { // the actual replace function you missed
    console.log(NOButton.textContent, url.pathname)
    const isEnglish = url.pathname.indexOf('en-US') != -1; // what is in the pathname
    const from = isEnglish ? 'en-US' : 'nb-NO'; // one or the other
    const to = isEnglish ? 'nb-NO' : 'en-US'; // one or the other
    url.pathname = url.pathname.replace(from, to)
    NOButton.textContent = isEnglish ? "Norsk" : "English"
    window.history.pushState('', '', url); // uncomment this after testing
  };

  NOButton.addEventListener('click', replace); // add the replace function to the button
  replace(); // initialise the button state
});
```

```html
<button id="NObutton">English</button>
```

Comment: If I understand this correct, I should replace the contents of my JS with what you wrote in your answer?
Forgive me, I have little to no knowledge about this.

Comment: @CharlieGolf Yes, my code replaces all your code

Comment: But will only replace ONE set. If you want to toggle I will change the script

Comment: Wow, thanks.
One last question if you don't mind: At the moment nothing happens when I click the button, nothing happens, I also don't see anything in the console log in browser.
I expect this is because I have not linked this properly somewhere, but can't figure out where i should reference the script.

Comment: I cannot guess. Need to see it live

Answer (score 0):

Where's the `replace` function ? :) you are calling it but I can't see it in your code.

Also, where's the second button ? you can use the same `replace()` function for the second button but add a param so you know which button was clicked.

See example below

```js
const myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

const replace = (btnId) => {
      let myUrl = window.location.href // https://stacksnippets.net/js
      
      myUrl = btnId === 'btn1' ? myUrl.replace('stack', 'myChange') : myUrl.replace('snippets', 'myChange')
      console.log(myUrl)
      // window.history.pushState('' , '', myUrl)
      // or window.location.href = myUrl
  }

  
myButtons.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = () => replace(btn.id))
```

```html
<button id="btn1" >Button1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button2</button>
```